# How do I reconnect to Memcache when forking in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I have a rails 3 application, and a script called by `rails runner`. This script forks and does some stuff in other processes. I do the proper thing with ActiveRecord before forking, where I disconnect-fork-reconnect and all that jazz.

My question is I also use memcache for the `Rails.cache` but should I be disconnecting-reconnecting that too for my forks? If so, how would I go about that in the rails way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should reconnect memcache after the fork.  You can see a discussion related to this at the [mod_rails](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_example_1_memcached_connection_sharing_harmful) documentation.

You can trigger memcache to [reconnect](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/MemCache.html#M000140)

```
Rails.cache.reset
```